# HashMap: Is there a way to search by hashcode and not by key?

Tags: java, hash, java-8, hashmap

I may sound completely wrong but:
I've read as many posts as I could find here about HashMap and hashcode . I did not get what I was looking for exactly. I am going to try to be as precise as I can.
Let's say I have a huge hashmap where :

- keys are of type `my_struct` and values as well
  Now, my_struct is made of 2 Lists that can have big sizes (so one entry has a respectable size on its own).
  **Keys and values have a special relation** : values are for sure already keys in the dictionary (something like ancenstor - descendant relation).
  I was wondering whether instead of storing values of my_struct , I could store an int and then using this "int as a key" to search for the relative entry. In pseudocode I could describe it as such:

```
  HashMap<my_struct, int> h = new HashMap<>(); 
  ......
  my_struct descendant = value;
  int id = a(value);     // returns an id for this value
  h.put(ancenstor, id);
  ...
  // after some time I want to find the corresponding value of id 
  int key = h.getValue(ancestor);  // == id
  if(h.contains(b(key)){
     ...
   }
```

So basically I am looking for :
a method : **a()** that turns a **mystruct -->int**
a method : b() that turns an **int ---> my struct**
Of course, both should be a 1-1 functions.
After reading Java8 documentation `a()` must be `int hashCode()` but what about b() is there something in Java?

Comment: Another Map that have id > struct ?

Comment: Firstly, if your map is storing the same object in the key and value you actually have a Set. What you you actually trying to achieve here? Is it just never have duplicate my_struct object in memory?

Comment: @Bohemian to be honest, values are actually my_struct + a character (a list of those 2 but I did not include such detail in my description because I think it does not offer something to the actual question) .  The idea behind this post is to save memory

Comment: The problem with using hashCode is there is a chance, however unlikely, the objects which not equal can produce the same hashCode. The only requirement for hashCode is that objects that are equal produce the same hashCode. Thus the idea of using hashCode for the key instead of the object itself is flawed.

Comment: If you want both-ways lookup struct->int, int->struct, then use two maps.  There's no rule that you're only allowed one data structure.

Comment: If you're worried about sizes of things = then  there are no things in maps, whether keys or values.  Only references.  So you might as well just have two maps. "X ->Y" and "Y -> X" where X and Y are both structures.  The size of a reference to a structure is the same as the size of a reference to an Integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> HashMap: Is there a way to search by hashcode and not by key?

Literally ... no.

---

OK, so I am assuming that this is a complete and accurate description of your real problem:

> So basically I am looking for :
>
> - a method : `a()` that maps a `my_struct` --> `int`
> - a method : `b()` that maps an `int` --> `my_struct`
>
> Of course, both should be a 1-1 functions.

Got that.

> After reading Java8 documentation `a()` must be `int hashCode()`

That is incorrect. `hashCode()` is not 1-1.  In general, multiple objects can have the same `hashCode()`.  Note that even identity hashcodes (as returned by `Object.hashCode`) are not guaranteed unique.

You could implement a `my_struct.hashCode` method that returns a unique integer, but the only *practical* way to do this would be to allocate a unique number when you create each `my_struct` instance, and store it in a field of the object.  And that has the problem that your `my_struct.equals` method has to return `true` **if and only if** the `my_struct` instances are the same instance.

But if you can live with those limitations, then `a()` can indeed be `my_struct.hashCode`.

If you generate the numbers for the `my_struct` objects sequentially starting at zero, you can add all of the `my_struct` instances to an `ArrayList<my_struct>` as you create them, then you can implement `b()` as `theList.get(int)`.

---

In code (not thread-safe!!):

```
public class my_struct {
    private static int next = 0;
    private static List<my_struct> all = new ArrayList<>();
    private int ordinal;
    // other fields

    public my_struct(...) {
       // initialize fields
       this.ordinal = next++;
       all.add(this);
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return other instanceof my_struct &&
             ((my_struct) other).ordinal = this.ordinal;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return ordinal;
    }

    public static my_struct(int ordinal) {
        return all.get(ordinal);
    }
}
```

---

But you should also be able to see that you don't *have to* use the ordinal as the hashcode and implement `hashCode()` and `equals(Object)` as above.  It depends on what else you are doing with these structs.

---

Note that this is not the same as using an `IdentityHashMap`.

Comment: This will prevent the garbage collection of the objects and establish a limit on the number of `my_struct` instances that can be created, i.e. 2³¹ (a bit less with common implementations). Even if you fix all the problems of this sketch, it will stop working in general when the 2³²th instance has been created.

Answer (score 2):

You might take a look at `IdentityHashMap` which does not rely on equals and only hashes on the identify hashCode itself.  This means that you can  have duplicate keys that might otherwise be considered equal.  So keys are only considered equal if they are the same reference.

Check out [IdentityHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) in the JavaDoc

Answer (score 1):

Since you are in charge of assigning `id`s, you can fake the other side of the relationship by keeping `my_struct` objects in an array list, and using their array index as the `id`.

This way, mapping from `my_struct` to `id` becomes a hash lookup, while mapping from `id` to `my_struct` becomes an array list look-up.

```
List<my_struct> mystructs = new ArrayList<my_struct>();
... add items to mystructs
Map<my_struct,Integer> toId = new HashMap<my_struct,Integer>();
for (int i = 0 ; i != mystructs.size() ; i++) {
    toId.put(mystructs.get(i), i);
}
```

Going from my_struct to id:

```
int id = toId.get(my_struct_object);
```

going from id to my_struct:

```
my_struct my_struct_object = mystructs.get(id);
```

Comment: Do you think this would be a better approach for memory usage? Instead of having one HashMap<my_struct, my_struct> , having 2 of HashMap<my_struct,int>?

Comment: There's no second hash map in the approach that I suggest. Replacing hash code id with array index id lets you get rid of the second hash map in favor of an array list, which is very economical in terms of memory.